# Angular Js - TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method "includes"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I am using angular js in my application. When I run my app on IE browser it shows following error.

```
 TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'
 at request (https://xxx.xx.xxx.com/js/app.js:32:20185)
 at u (https://xxx.xx.xxx.com/js/base.js:5:30028)
 at Anonymous function (https://xxxx.xx.xxxx.com/js/base.js:5:30210)
 at $eval (https://xxxx.xx.xxxx.com/js/base.js:6:5594)
 at $digest (https://xxxx.xx.xxxx.com/js/base.js:6:4028)
 at $apply (https://xxxx.xx.xxxx.com/js/base.js:6:5883)
 at Anonymous function (https://xxxx.xx.xxxx.com/js/base.js:4:7566)
 at i (https://xxxx.xx.xxxx.com/js/base.js:4:19305)
 at s (https://xxxx.xx.xxxx.com/js/base.js:4:7480)
 at ae (https://xxxx.xx.xxxx.com/js/base.js:4:7676)
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

includes() is not supported on Internet Explorer. The simplest alternative is to use indexOf, like this:

```
if(your_string.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
    //statements
}
```